# Sobrescrever dados em tabela com DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Toda vez que faço um change no select ele chama esta função, ela pega o id do imposto selecionado e faz as pesquisa pelas(filhas) regras de impostos, preciso atualizar a tabela toda vez que dá change porém acontece esse erro: 
DataTables warning: table id=regrasimpostos - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

```
function pesquisaRegrasImpostos(imposto){
    if (imposto != "") {
        $.ajax({
            url: `/pesquisa/regraimposto/${imposto}`,
            success: function(data){
                $("#regrasimpostos").DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": `/pesquisa/regraimposto/${imposto}`,
                    "columns": [
                        {"data" : "impostoNome"},
                        {"data" : "modelo"},
                        {"data" : "pessoa"},
                        {"data" : "contribuinte"},
                        {"data" : "estado"},
                        {"data" : "cfop"},
                        {
                            "data" : null,
                            defaultContent: `<a href="#" title="Editar" data-id="impostoID" onclick="editarRegra('variavel')"><i class="edit icon"></i></a>`
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Se o datatables for `1.10.xxx` pode adicionar a opção `destroy: true,` no construtor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não deve inicializar o componente mais de uma vez, assim como também não faz sentido realizar duas requições ajax para popular a tabela, veja que você faz uma no início da sua function e outra quando declara a url no atributo `ajax` do construtor do `DataTable`.

Inicialize o componente apenas uma vez, no carregamento da página, e utilize sua api para alterar o conteúdo, [ajax.url().load()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#regrasimpostos").DataTable({
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": false,
    "data" : null,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "impostoNome"
      },
      {
        "data": "modelo"
      },
      {
        "data": "pessoa"
      },
      {
        "data": "contribuinte"
      },
      {
        "data": "estado"
      },
      {
        "data": "cfop"
      },
      {
        "data": null,
        defaultContent: `<a href="#" title="Editar" data-id="impostoID" onclick="editarRegra('variavel')"><i class="edit icon"></i></a>`
      }

    ]
  });
});



function pesquisaRegrasImpostos(imposto) {
  if (imposto != "") {
    var datatable = $("#regrasimpostos").dataTable().api();
    datatable
      .ajax
      .url('/pesquisa/regraimposto/${imposto}')
      .load();

  }
}
```

```css
@import '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="regrasimpostos" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-name="impostoNome">Nome</th>
      <th data-name="modelo">Modelo</th>
      <th data-name="pessoa">Pessoa</th>
      <th data-name="contribuinte">Contribuinte</th>
      <th data-name="estado">Estado</th>
      <th data-name="cfop">CFOP</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito bom amigo, show!!! valew!!